# Make this keyword refer to instance rather than window object

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

In the code below I create an object called Slates and add some functions to it.

```js
"use strict";

function Slates() {
    this.canvas;
    this.ctx;
    this.width;
    this.height;
}

Slates.prototype.init = function() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.resize();
};

Slates.prototype.resize = function() {
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.canvas.width = this.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.height;
    console.log("resizing");
};

Slates.prototype.render = function() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,100,.5)";
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};

window.onload = function() {
    var slates = new Slates();
    slates.init();
    window.onresize = slates.resize;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(slates.render);
};
```

The problem is that when I pass the function `slates.render` as a callback into a function
such as `window.requestAnimationFrame` the `this` keyword refers to the `window` object rather than the `Slates` instance, and therefore I get a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined

How do I fix this so that it refers to the instance of my object instead?  Here is a link to a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raBJqB).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use, for example, `Function.prototype.bind`, which will return a function but with constant this value:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(slates.render.bind(slates))
```

or wrap this invocation into another function:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { slates.render() })
```

Answer (score 4):

**L-values and r-values**

In programming, there are two kinds of expressions: l-values ("l" for left) and r-values ("r" for right). An l-value is something that can be *assigned to* while an r-value is something that we can *assign* to something else. For example, say we had the following HTML

```
<div id="my-div" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
```

and the following JS:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");
```

Then we could use `myDiv.style.backgroundColor` as an l-value (i.e. assign something to it)

```
myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black"; // myDiv.style.backgroundColor is an l-value
```

or as an r-value (assign it / pass it to something else):

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = myDiv.style.backgroundColor // now both are "black"
```

When we have a "dot chain" like in the above `myDiv.style.backgroundColor`, its value in an expression is equal to the value of the *last* link in the chain. So when we use `myDiv.style.backgroundColor` in an expression, we are simply using the `backgroundColor`. Assigning this to a new element, say `newDiv`, does not create any sort of link between `myDiv.style` and `newDiv.style`.

Likewise, when you assign `slates.render` to `window.onload`, you're assigning the `render` function only - there is no longer any connection to `slates`.

You might wonder though... okay, but shouldn't `this` be a link back to `slates`? Well, think about it, you never actually assigned anything to `this` in your `render` function, right? You just used it. The language engine supplies the value of `this` for you. Ordinary variables/properties in JS, e.g. `slates` or `slates.render` can be either l-values *or* r-values, depending on the context. However, the `this` keyword is only valid as an `r-value`. If we try to assign directly to the `this` keyword, we will see an error like this:

[image]

The error says what we already know -- that `this` is not a valid l-value. So where does it get its value from?

This brings us to a discussion of scope in JS and why `this` is different from other variables in an important way.

**Lexical scope (how variables work)**

In JS, variables are *lexically scoped*, meaning that the value of a variable in a function call is determined not by the scope of the call, but rather by the scope of the function's definition.

```
var x = {name: "outer"};
function y() {
    var x = {name: "inner"};
    return function() {
        console.log(x.name);
    };
}

var z = y(); // z is a function here
z(); // logs "inner", not "outer" because JS is lexically scoped
```

In this example, we define a function `y` which itself returns a function which gets assigned to `z`. When `z` executes, it does `console.log(x.name)`, but the question is... which `x` should it refer to? If JS were dynamically scoped, then we might expect it to print "outer", since this is the `x` defined at the same "scope" as the variable `z`. But it doesn't. It prints "inner" because JS is lexically scoped, meaning that `x` is equal to the `x` which was in scope *at the time of definition*.

**Dynamic Scope (how the `this` keyword works)**

If the `this` keyword was lexically scoped like other variables in JS, the code in your post would have worked. But it's not. While normal variables in JS are lexically scoped, the `this` keyword is *not* lexically scoped. It has dynamic scope. Meaning that its value depends not on the context in which your function is defined, but rather the context in which your function *executes*. What context did you execute it in? The window object! If you imagine the load event being called like `window.onload()` then this becomes more clear.

In fact, this is the behavior we want. Because if you had set a click event on a button, then you might do something like:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById("my-input-box");
function myFunc() {
    alert("Uh oh, you typed " + this.value);
}
inputBox.onchange = myFunc;
```

This is the same behavior. What's a little confusing is the fact that `window` is also the *default* `this` value. (More on that below).

**With a few exceptions -- including the `new` operator and the `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods -- the only way to pass a `this` value into a function in JS is to call it on an object, like this:**

```
object.method(); // this now refers to object within `method`
```

**An analogy**

Here's a real world analogy. Say that you have a ball. Define a method on the ball called `kick`. The method is defined as `move your leg to exert force on *it*`. The "it" in that phrase is much like `this` in JavaScript. It's meaning is determined by context in which it is used, or in this case in which context the function is *called*. Without the ball, `kick` still has meaning but the `it` which it references is not defined. What I'm kicking is unknown.

When you pass a method to the window.onload handler like that, you're passing in the `kick` function only, which on its own has no connection to the `ball`. Only when we call it like `ball.kick()` does `kick` get a `this` value of `ball`. In real life, there is no "default" it value. We don't assume that it refers to, say, the earth if we're not sure. Unlike real life however, JS *does* have a default `it`/`this` value. That default value is the `window` object. Trying to reason why the default is `window` is probably futile - it's just an implementation decision that was made.

**One solution**

In your case, the easiest thing to do is to use the `bind` function. The `bind` function (introduced in the last version of JS) allows you to *bind* a certain `this` value to a function, returning the new `this`-bound function as its return value. So for instance, if you had a function like

```
Ball.prototype.kick = function() {

    this.touch();
    this.move();
    console.log(this);

}
```

and you did

```
myBall = new Ball();
kickBall = ball.kick.bind(myBall); // returns a new function, doesn't affect the original ball.kick
```

Then you could call `kickBall` without the normal `ball.kick()` syntax and its `this` value would be `myBall`.

```
kickBall(); // myBall
window.setTimeout(myBall.kick, 1000); // window
```

**A simpler solution**

The simpler (and more common) way is to just assign a function which itself calls `slates.render()` to `window.onload`, like so:

```
window.onload = function() {

   slates.render(); // this works because doing obj.method() passes obj as a this value to method

};
```

**Further reading**

Here's a better writeup of what `this` means in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/2407870

Comment: You might want to mention an alternative to using `bind` is to wrap your function call in a closure such as `function() { myBall.kick(); }`

Comment: @naomik I'm trying to figure out how to explain that method in a meaningful way - if you have an idea of how, please feel free to add to/edit the answer. And thanks for the compliment.

Comment: +1 great answer and analogy. Thanks for taking the time to write all this out!